# dereferencing hash without creating a local copy

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

I the code bellow line 9 creates a local copy of a hash. Any changes to the %d will not provide changes to global %h variable (line: 5). I have to use reference (line: 8) to provide changes to %h.

Is there any way to dereference hash in a sub without creating a local copy?
I am asking since I have complicated record with many references and navigating around it with dereferences would be much easier.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  2 use strict;
  3 use warnings;
  4 
  5 my %h;
  6 sub a {
  7 
  8     my $href = shift;
  9     my(%d) = %{$href};   # this will make a copy of global %h
 10     
 11     $$href{1}=2;     # this will make a change in global %h
 12     $d{2}=2;         # this will not a change in global %h
 13 }   
 14 a(\%h);
 15 print scalar (keys %h) . "\n";
```

## ----------------

Thanks for the replies.

The question is can I make some kind of "alias/bind" to %h in a sub.
I would like to change the context of %h in a sub with %d.
Whenever I create %d he makes local copy of %h - is there any way to avoid that or do I have to use references all the time?

## ----------------

One more time :) I know how $href's work. I read tutorial / manuals / docs etc.
I didn't find the answer there - I assume that this is not possible since it wasn't written there, but who knows.

I want to accomplish such behavior:

```
  6 sub a {
  7     $h{"1"}=2;
  8 }
```

Which is equivalent to that:

```
  6 sub a {
  8      my $href = shift;
  11     $$href{1}=2;     # this will make a change in global %h
  11     $href->{1}=2;    # this will make a change in global %h
```

Now how to do that with the help of %d - is it actually possible?

```
6 sub a {
7        my %d = XXXXXXXXX
.. }
```

What should I put under XXXXXXXXX to point to %h without creating a local copy?

Comment: Out of curiosity -- what's wrong with the two methods you list (the inline dereference with $$ and the arrow operator)?

Comment: $$ is okey. I am just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a local alias of the value, you need to use Perl's package variables, which can be aliased using the typeglob syntax (and `local` to scope the alias):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;

sub a {
    my $href = shift;

    our %alias; # create the package variable (for strict)

    local *alias = $href;
        # here we tell perl to install the hashref into the typeglob 'alias'
        # perl will automatically put the hashref into the HASH slot of
        # the glob which makes %alias refer to the passed in hash.
        # local is used to limit the change to the current dynamic scope.
        # effectively it is doing:  *{alias}{HASH} = $href

    $$href{1}=2;     # this will make a change in global %h
    $alias{2}=2;     # this will also make a change in global %h
}
a(\%h);
print scalar (keys %h) . "\n";  # prints 2
```

This is a fairly advanced technique, so be sure to read the Perl docs on `local` and `typeglobs` so you understand exactly what is going on (in particular, any subs called from within the `a` subroutine after the `local` will also have `%alias` in scope, since `local` denotes a dynamic scope.  The localization will end when `a` returns.)

If you can install `Data::Alias` or one of the other aliasing modules from `CPAN` you can avoid the package variable and create a lexical alias.  The above method is the only way to do it without additional modules.

Comment: Agreed, aliases are best avoided unless one has a *really good reason* for using them. I am curious as to why the OP is rejecting simply using a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways of using a hash reference:

1. One you yourself were using

   ```
   $$href{'key2'} = "key2";
   ```
2. Pointed out above:

   ```
   $href->{'key1'} = "key1";
   ```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you

```
$href->{1} = 2;
print scalars (keys %{$href});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Following code shows how to dereference using the arrow operator (and yes, without creating a local variable)

Read [this](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html) for a tutorial on dereferencing and the different types of dereferencing possible.

```
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper::Simple;

my %h;
sub a {
    my $href = shift;

    #dereference using the arrow operator - *preferred*
    $href->{name} = "John"; 

}

a(\%h); #Passing the reference of the hash
print Dumper(%h);
```

Why do you need to pass the hash which is a global, as an argument to the sub-routine in the first place?

1. Avoid using global variables.
2. Preferably, don't change the state of *any* variables after they have been assigned.